# Wrong position of picturebox when turned visible in a scrollable panel

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, picturebox

**CONTEXT :**

I'm developping a windows form c# app with visual studio 2017.

The app has a scrollable panel (`AutoScroll = true`) filled with buttons.

Each button is associated to a picturebox.

They both are overlapping and have the same size and are sharing the same `Tag` attribute.

The tags are: 0 for the btn0 and picBox0, 1 for the btn1 and picBox1, etc...

When a button is clicked, its `Visible` attribute is set to `false` and the corresponding picBox's `Visible` attribute is set to `true`.

**MY QUESTION :**

When the picBox's visibility is set to true, it doesn't spawn/appear at the position it's placed in the designer of the form...

It looks like it doesn't spawn at a relative place in the parent panel...

Here's pictures to help yall understand my problem:

BEFORE:
[image]

AFTER:
[image]

You can barely see the borders of the picBox5, but they are there! (Zoom in! haha)

Before you ask:

YES, the picBox has the good `Tag` (5)

The position is fine in the designer and is not changed when the app is runing.

I looked with the debugger and the position seems fine...

I'm wondering if the picBox takes its position from the parent form instead of the parent scrollable panel?

How do I make the picture box spawn at the appropriate position?

Comment: Only you can answer why that one is different - is it premade or at runtime? if its premade check it got made in the scrollbox not behind or something and that its anchors are the same as all the others

Comment: When the picture box is visible by default, its position is ok, but when I make it visible with the button, its position is "ok" but isn't at the right place in the panel... Thanks for the hints tho! The anchors are the same for all the picturboxes/buttons. And the problem happens for all the pictureboxes of the second and third row, not just this one! (:

Comment: The Location is the sum of its Top/Left and and the container's AutoScrollPosition.Top/Left.

Comment: @LoukMo shame you didnt provide all the necessary info in the original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was reset the location of the target picBox taking in consideration the position of the scrollbar:

```
picBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(picBox.Location.X + panel.AutoScrollPosition.X, picBox.Location.Y + panel.AutoScrollPosition.Y);
picBox.Visible = true;
```

You also need to make sure that the **change of visibility is AFTER the relocation**.

This visibility change makes the scrollbar change its position and it makes the relocation wrong.